# Redirect to .scala.html file (Scala Play) only shows plain text

Tags: javascript, ajax, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I just implemented the Google OAuth hybrid server side flow which requires an AJAX call for retrieving an access token. After I did the AJAX call (stored the token etc.) I would like the server to display some content using a file called home.scala.html.

```
//called when client has confirmed the OAuth Login dialog
function signInCallback(authResult) { 

        if (authResult['code']) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:9000/storeauthcode",
                ...
                success: function(result) {
                    //access token was saved
                    //now redirect to the home area of the website
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost:9000/home");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    //handle error appropriately here
                    ...

                }

            });
           }
    }
```

However, if I get the token and everything works fine, I see the template code of my home.scala.html file (so it prints the html markup) but does not interpret this as Html that should be rendered by the browser.

How can I make the browser render the home.scala.html file as an Html file and not as plain text?

PS: Does it even make sense to do a redirect here or should the content be displayed on the same page? Looks a little bit weird when the Google login window is closed and the user has to wait until he is redirected to the actual site.

How should I get this content (AJAX, AngularJS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play generates Javascript code to handle routing from client-side code back to your application. That is called [Javascript Routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting).

First you create a router:

```
public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
        response().setContentType("text/javascript");
        return ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
                controllers.routes.javascript.Users.storeAuthCode()));
    }
```

then add it to your routes file:

```
GET /javascriptRoutes  controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
```

and to your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
```

Last but not least, the code to invoke it would look something like this:

```
$.ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.Users.storeAuthCode())
  .done( /*...*/ )
  .fail( /*...*/ );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the argument as type `Html` in `home.scala.html`. Your code would look something like this:

```
@(title: String)(code: Html)

<head>
  <title>@title</title>
</head>
<body>
  @code
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. The problem is that if I redirect to a scala.html page via Javascript, I see plain text and no HTML. So I don't understand what this has to do with parameters in my template.

Comment: Oh, I see. So basically the `scala.html` files are not HTML per se. That is code that's going to be compiled into HTML. You should generate a [Javascript router](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting) for that purpose.

Comment: This is obviously the case. I know that. But this does not solve the problem. So the question is bascially, how can you make the server compile a .scala.html file when you access the respective route specified in your routes file?